# How to eat coconut oil? More details inside!

Tags: oil, coconut

I'm having trouble eating coconut oil by the spoonful, I can't stand the oily fatty feeling in my mouth. It makes me gag. However, I do want to eat it for health benefits.

I can eat ~5g of fructose (including that of sucrose) a day, so mixing it in with anything that contains fructose is not an option.

I do not eat dairy or beans/lentils or meat or any type of grains or nuts and I do not fry anything. I do not drink coffee either, I do drink green tea however. I eat soup, but coconut oil in soup is a ***very*** bad idea. I can't not eat soup because I cannot prepare my meal by only boiling otherwise with all the ingredients that I need to eat daily. Also, I do not own and can't afford a blender. I own a mixer, but it's very bad and doesn't grind anything.

Due to fructose content (and oftentimes price), I don't eat much fruit, I do eat some vegetables though.

How can I make something out of coconut oil that doesn't contain sweeteners, above 5g of fructose, isn't dairy, meat, fried, and doesn't have that disgusting pure oil feeling in your mouth?

I do like the taste of coconuts, but only when it comes in coconut meat. Coconuts however cost a lot more where I'm from and I can't afford it, so I have to eat coconut oil.

I want to eat quite a few table spoons of it, and I'm failing to think of a way to eat it. Basically I'm looking for a somewhat cheap way within my diet restrictions to eat coconut oil, which wouldn't make me gag.

Comment: If you don't eat dairy, meat, grains, nuts, most fruits and you only eat some vegetables... what do you eat?

Comment: Why is sauteeing/frying not an option? You eat vegetables, you want to eat oil... put them together?

Comment: @Catija I eat fish.

Comment: @Jefromi Even if it was, there wouldn't be enough oil, but it's not an option anyway. And because I don't eat enough vegetables to make myself a big bowl of them with 5 tablespoons of coconut oil. Also, it's thick in room temperature, and I generally do not like raw vegetables with oil - I don't like the oily feeling in my mouth that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Stephie No, they are not. Sorry, I will edit and add that to the post.

Comment: So you eat raw vegetables only? And fish. And soup made of... broth and maybe fish? Anything else? It's really hard for anyone to suggest anything you could possibly make with coconut oil when it seems you don't actually eat anything you could add it to.

Comment: @Jefromi No, I eat boiled vegetables with fish soup. I don't eat anything else, but I don't mind adding something that isn't in the list of "I don't eat that" in the first post, and anything that's relatively cheap and doesn't contain more than 5g of fructose per 100g of added coconut oil. It can be cooked, baked, something-else. Important thing is that it isn't as oily as pure oil, which is what makes me gag.

Comment: So... you can bake or roast vegetables with oil, but not saute them?

Comment: @Jefromi - Yes, I can use an oven, however not with vegetables. Unless they add mass for me to eat with coconut oil and have very little of any type of vitamins or minerals and are dirt cheap.

Answer (score 4):

Given the restrictions you've provided, as far as I can tell the only thing you eat that could possibly take on a decent amount of oil without being obviously greasy is mashed or pureed vegetables, either on their own or as part of a pureed soup. For example, any starchy vegetable (potatoes, winter squash, carrots, etc) can take up a decent amount of oil when mashed or when pureed into a soup. Even less starchy things like broccoli and cauliflower might do okay.

I can't think of any way to add a bunch of oil to a piece of fish.

If you were willing to saute or roast vegetables with oil, that'd let you use a fair amount (especially roasting starchier ones) but apparently that's not allowed.

And since that's all you eat... that's all I've got. If you remove nearly every commonly eaten food and half the cooking methods for the few foods you do eat, your options are going to be pretty limited.

In general if you want to try to look for ideas for this, I'd look for recipes using butter and the things you eat. It's also solid and unpleasant to eat at room temperature, but way more common in recipes than coconut oil so you'll probably find more ideas.

Comment: I was looking for new foods from the types of foods that I can eat to try with coconut oil. Like some kinda cocoa mix or something, for example.

Comment: @Jack I can't think of anything pleasant to make out of cocoa powder and coconut oil without using any grains or dairy or anything. I don't know what other random things are somehow not excluded by the "I don't eat anything" restrictions you've given us, but playing a guessing game of "would you eat X?" is not really the kind of specific, answerable question we're looking for. So if you want to ask "is there some way I can combine coconut oil and X to make something edible?" go for it, but please don't ask us to try to guess what you'll eat.